# Class with @Secured annotation not created when implement interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the problem and cannot understand how to fix it, any help will be appraised.
I need secure the REST method with some auth and I have the few roles in my application. I place the `@Secured` annotation at my method in my class, that implement some interface and Spring not creating a bean (`@Controller` in my case) without any log message. But if the class didn’t implement the interface – the bean is created well.

In code it looks like there:

**Controller:**

```java
public class Controller implements API {
   @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
   @RequestMapping(value = "/one/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String test() {
      return "ONE";
   }
}
```

**Interface:**

```java
public interface API {
   String test();
}
```

Controller bean is not creating in my case. But if I remove the `implements API` all will work fine, bean will be created and the security will work.

I use XML-based configuration and place

```xml
<secutiry:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled">
```

at *mvc-config.xml* to enable the annotations.

I traced it and if annotation placed at method in class that didn’t implement interface, Spring uses `MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.MethodSecurityMetadataSourcePointcut` when it building the context, but when class implements the interface – Spring use `TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut`.

`@RolesAllowed` gives the same effect.

Checked at version

```xml
<spring.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-security.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
```

and

```xml
<spring.version>4.3.23.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-security.version>4.2.13.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
```

The latest *Spring Boot* has the same effect.

Did anybody fix the same issue? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this- 
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
at class level in your config class , we can enable annotation-based security using the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation on any @Configuration instance. For example, the following would enable Spring Security’s @Secured annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm ussing the XML configuration and turn on annotation in
```<secutiry:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"> ```.
If remove interface all work fine, so the problem in some deep Spring mechanism, I guess.